# How to extract xml attributes using Xpath in Pig?

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, attributes, apache-pig

I wanted to extract the attributes form an xml using Pig Latin.

This is a sample of the xml file

```
<CATALOG>
<BOOK>
<TITLE test="test1">Hadoop Defnitive Guide</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Tom White</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CLOUDERA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>24.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2012</YEAR>
</BOOK>
</CATALOG>
```

I used this script but it didn't work:

```
REGISTER ./piggybank.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A =  LOAD './books.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('BOOK') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'BOOK/TITLE/@test'), XPath(x, 'BOOK/PRICE');
dump B;
```

The output was:

```
(,24.90)
```

I hope someone can help me with this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you meant `'BOOK/TITLE/@test'` instead of `'BOOK/AUTHOR/@test'`? The `AUTHOR` element has no `test` attribute.

Comment: oh yes, in the actual code I used Title. Sorry about that.

Comment: If `BOOK/PRICE` works with the given focus, then `BOOK/TITLE/@test` should work also, unless attributes are not supported with piggybank. I assume `BOOK/TITLE` works as well? You may try `BOOK//@*`, which should give you all attributes under BOOK.

Comment: alternatively, it is possible that the `dump` command does not work well with attributes.... Try `string(BOOK/TITLE/@test)`.

Comment: BOOK/TITLE works just fine.
I used BOOK//@* it gave the same thing. 
Using String I got an exception.

Comment: It is not `String`, but `string`. It is case-sensitive. It is a very basic function, if it is not supported, I guess Pig does not really support XPath?

Comment: I used both actually and I got different exceptions.

Comment: "an exception" is not very helpful and can mean anything. Please update (click [edit]) your question with your findings so far, it will further help understand what's happening.

Comment: If you have an exception, you have a precious clue -- and you're not telling us what it is? `String` (capitalized) may give some kind of syntax error, but the exception for the XPath expression using `string` could be very helpful to know.

Comment: I am sorry I was busy, I temporarily got what I need but using regular expressions not Xpath . For the exception it was : string could not be resolved. If you need more details I can post the log file tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 bugs in piggybank's XPath class:

1. The ignoreNamespace logic breaks searching for XML attributes
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4751
2. The ignoreNamepace parameter is defaulted to true and cannot be overwritten
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4752

Here is my workaround using XPathAll:

```
XPathAll(x, 'BOOK/TITLE/@test', true, false).$0 as (test:chararray)
```

Also if you still need to ignore namespaces:

```
XPathAll(x, '//*[local-name()=\'BOOK\']//*[local-name()=\'TITLE\']/@test', true, false).$0 as (test:chararray)
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue and  tried same way you suggested but it didn't work for me. 
`Returning error. productsOneByOne = FOREACH allProducts GENERATE XPathAll(x, 'product/@productID', true, false).$0 as (productid:chararray); ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025: <line 4, column 57> Invalid field projection. Projected field [x] does not exist in schema: data:chararray `
my post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887260/hadoop-pig-xpath-returning-empty-attribute-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887260/hadoop-pig-xpath-returning-empty-attribute-value)