# Hadoop pig XPath returning empty attribute value

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am using cloudera Hadoop 2.6, pig 0.15 versions.

I am trying to extract data from xml file. Below you can see part of xml file.

```
<product productID="MICROLITEMX1600LAMP">
  <basicInfo>
                <category lang="NL" id="OT1006">Output Accessoires</category>
  </basicInfo>
</product>
```

I can dump node values but not attribute values using XPath() function. You can see the code below which is returning empty tuples instead of productID.

```
    DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();   
    allProducts = LOAD '/pathtofile/sample.xml' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('product') AS (data:chararray);
    productsOneByOne = FOREACH allProducts GENERATE XPath(data, 'product/@productID') AS productid:chararray
    dump productsOneByOne;
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789734/how-to-extract-xml-attributes-using-xpath-in-pig

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but it didn't work for me. Returning error.
productsOneByOne = FOREACH allProducts GENERATE XPathAll(x, 'product/@productID', true, false).$0 as (productid:chararray);
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:
<line 4, column 57> Invalid field projection. Projected field [x] does not exist in schema: data:chararray.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind  Thank you for refering link. It helped me  alot. I posted answer myself . please check  it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to [How to extract xml attributes using Xpath in Pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789734/how-to-extract-xml-attributes-using-xpath-in-pig)

Bug is there in XPath.java as it is ignoring 4th parameter.

By adding following code in XPath.java and complied issue is resolved. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/branches/branch-0.15/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/xml/XPath.java

```
if(input.size() > 3){
  ignoreNamespace=input.get(3);
}
```

above code should be added before

```
if (ignoreNamespace) {
                xpathString = createNameSpaceIgnoreXpathString(xpathString);
 }
```