# Extract attribute value in XML using xpath in PIG

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-pig

I have following input XML

```
<Type>  
    <Source>        
        <TimeStamp>2016-02-19T12:27:06.387Z</TimeStamp>
        <IPAddress IPVersion="IPv4">x.xx.xxx.xxx</IPAddress>
        <Port>64435</Port>
        <DNS_Name>x.xx.xxx.xxx.range9-27.abc.com</DNS_Name>
    </Source>
 </Type>
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the values from the above tags using below code.

```
REGISTER piggybank-0.15.0.jar
            DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

        A =  LOAD 'test.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Type') as (x:chararray);
        B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
                               XPath(x, 'Source/TimeStamp')
                               ,XPath(x, 'Source/IPAddress')
                               ,XPath(x, 'Source/IPAddress/@IPVersion')
                               ,XPath(x, 'Source/Port')
                               ,XPath(x, 'Source/DNS_Name');
```

When I dump B, I get the following output where the value of IPVersion is missing.

```
(2016-02-19T12:27:06.387Z,x.xx.xxx.xxx,,64435,x.xx.xxx.xxx.range9-27.abc.com)
```

can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: i think from XPathAll you can achieve this. pls see my answer

Comment: If it is Okay... can you flag up "accepted by owner" as well

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 bugs in piggybank's [XPath](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/branch-0.14/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/xml/XPath.java) class:

1. The ignoreNamespace logic breaks searching for XML attributes
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4751
2. The ignoreNamepace parameter is defaulted to true and cannot be overwritten
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4752

see the work around with `XPathAll` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789734/how-to-extract-xml-attributes-using-xpath-in-pig)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to tell the class name for the XpathALL? Because I'm getting an error while Define the XpathALL alise.

Comment: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/xml/XPathAll.html

Comment: piggybank-0.12.0.jar has this class and you need to check your jar version has this class or not

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It's throwing the below error   2016-05-26 06:56:19,884 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathALL using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: have you  registered piggybank jar version in which you have XpathAll class?

Comment: like this REGISTER ./piggybank.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath(); similary you have to defile XpathAll as showed in this example

Comment: grunt> REGISTER piggybank-0.12.0.jar
grunt> DEFINE XPathALL org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathALL();
grunt> A =  LOAD '/user/b7799994/XML/mCIR_XML.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Infringement') as (x:chararray);
grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPathALL(x, 'Source/IPAddress/@IPVersion', true, false).$0 as (test:chararray);
2016-05-26 09:51:30,537 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathALL using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: I registered and defined, but it's throwing the above error as you see

Comment: I have a doubt that your piggybank jar is not in classpath. if its relative path you can give like this REGISTER /home/piggybank-0.12.0.jar also see http://www.mzan.com/article/36240294-parsing-a-nested-xml-string-from-a-hive-table-using-pig.shtml

Comment: @Sathyaraj: checked class path to Sorted out all errors ?

Comment: I've given the correct class path. Still it's not working

Comment: do these 1) in unix bash, go to lib folder where piggybankxxx.jar is there 2) jar -tvf piggybank-0.12.0.jar and paste output here. In that XpathAll class should be printed in shell.