# XPath for stackoverflow dump files

Tags: xpath, apache-pig

Am working with file with following format:

```
<badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="1" Name="Teacher"   Date="2009-09-30T15:17:50.66"/>
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Teacher"  Date="2009-09-30T15:17:50.69"/>                
</badges>
```

I am using pig xmlloader to fetch this xml data into hdfs.

```
A =  LOAD '/badges' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('row') as (x:chararray);
B = foreach A generate xpath(x, '/row@Id'). 
Dump B;
```

Output I get () - No values.

I want the file output as text i.e  1,1,Teacher,2009-09-30T15:17:50.66. How can I do this?

Comment: try `/row/@*` to get value of each attribute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pig xmlloader, but `/row@Id` has two problems:

- It's not valid XPath
- If it were, it would be an absolute path

Try:

```
B = foreach A generate xpath(x, 'row/@Id').
```

It uses valid syntax and a relative path.

Comment: Can you explain.... The script you gave me to try . It is same as I was trying before.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPathAll for extracting attributes.Xpath has an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789734/how-to-extract-xml-attributes-using-xpath-in-pig) when it comes to attributes.

```
REGISTER '/path/piggybank-0.15.0.jar'; -- Use the jar name you downloaded
DEFINE XPathAll org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathAll();

B = foreach A generate XPathAll(x, 'row/@Id', true, false).$0 as (id:chararray);
```

Comment: I tired this and included the XPathAll in the define :                               DEFINE XPathAll  org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathAll; but I get an error that  Could not resolve XPathAll.ARGUMENTS.values using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1492083518074.log

Comment: you need to register piggybank.jar. Download piggybank.jar and register it.I've updated the script.

Comment: That has been great help for me!                                                                  I got the output now :                                                                                                               (1,1,Teacher,2009-09-30T15:17:50.66)
(2,3,Teacher,2009-09-30T15:17:50.69)
(3,13,Teacher,2009-09-30T15:17:50.69)
(4,14,Teacher,2009-09-30T15:17:50.69)
(5,22,Teacher,2009-09-30T15:17:50.69)

Comment: Is there any way I remove the brackets at the start and end...  I tried modifying LOAD '/user/training/badgesxml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('row') as x:chararray; but that did not work for me.

Comment: No, that is how the relationis printed on the console.If you write it to a file the brackets will not be there.See here for relations https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Relations%2C+Bags%2C+Tuples%2C+Fields

Comment: Your inquisitive mind helped me a lot today. Thank you!